# Tasking: Very slow response

Tags: task, ada, gnat

My actual program creates a task which I does not react to control messages as it should. As it has grown pretty large, I present a short test program with the same control logic. It creates a background task which repeates a loop every 0.1s. Depending on a protected flag "running" it prints out an 'a', or does nothing. When I set "running", the program goes off immediately, printing the 'a's. But when I set "stopreq", it takes seconds, sometimes well over 10, until it stops. I would expect a response time of 0.1 or 0.2s.

Anybody has an explanation and a solution?

My main program opens a window with 3 buttons: "Start", which calls the subprogram Start below, "Stop", which calls Request_Stop, and "Quit" calling Request_Quit. I am working on a PC running Linux.

Here comes the body of my Tasking package. If you need more, just tell me and I post the other parts.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;

package body Tasking is
   
   t_step:  constant Duration:= 0.1;
   dti:     Duration;
      
   protected Sync is
      procedure Start;              -- sim. shall start
      procedure Request_Stop;           -- sim. shall stop
      procedure Stop_If_Req;
      function Is_Running return Boolean;   -- sim. is running
      procedure Request_Quit;           -- sim.task shall exit
      function Quit_Requested return Boolean;   -- quit has been requested
      procedure Reset_Time;
      procedure Increment_Time (dt: Duration);
      procedure Delay_Until;
   private
      running:  Boolean:= false;
      stopreq:  Boolean:= false;
      quitreq:  Boolean:= false;
      ti:   Ada.Calendar.Time;
   end Sync;
   
   protected body Sync is
      
      procedure Start is begin running:= true; end Start;
      
      procedure Request_Stop is
      begin
     if running then stopreq:= true; end if;
      end Request_Stop;
      
      procedure Stop_If_Req is
      begin
     if stopreq then
        running:= false;
        stopreq:= false;
     end if;
      end Stop_If_Req;
      
      function Is_Running return Boolean is begin return running; end Is_Running;
      
      procedure Request_Quit is begin quitreq:= true; end Request_Quit;
      
      function Quit_Requested return Boolean
      is begin return quitreq; end Quit_Requested;
      
      procedure Reset_Time is begin ti:= Ada.Calendar.Clock; end Reset_Time;
      
      procedure Increment_Time (dt: Duration) is
      begin
     ti:= Ada.Calendar."+"(ti, dt);
     dti:= dt;
      end Increment_Time;
      
      procedure Delay_Until is
     use type Ada.Calendar.Time;
     now:   Ada.Calendar.Time;
      begin
     now:= Ada.Calendar.Clock;
     while ti < now loop    -- while time over
        ti:= ti + dti;
     end loop;
     delay until ti;
      end Delay_Until;
      
   end Sync;
   
   
   task body Thread is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("starting task");
      while not Sync.Quit_Requested loop
     if sync.Is_Running then
        sync.Increment_Time (t_step);
        sync.Delay_Until;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put("a");
        sync.Stop_If_Req;
     else
        delay t_step;
        sync.Reset_Time;
     end if;
       end loop;
   end Thread;
   
   
   procedure Start is
   begin
      Sync.Start;
   end Start;
   
   function Is_Running return Boolean is
   begin
      return Sync.Is_Running;
   end Is_Running;
   
   procedure Request_Stop is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("");
      Sync.Request_Stop;
   end Request_Stop;
   
   procedure Request_Quit is
   begin
      Sync.Request_Quit;
   end Request_Quit;
   
end Tasking;
```

Comment: May be an endless loop with `delay until` time in the past..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is too poorly described and commented for me to understand what you want it to do.

But using a "delay until" statement in a protected operation (Sync.Delay_Until) is not correct -- it is a "bounded error". If it works, it probably blocks all other calls to that protected object until the delay has expired. I suggest you should start there when you try to correct the code.

Comment: Just add to what Hiklas comment, protected object should be used to protect shared data, not task control. In order to control a task, use task entry as shown below for example. 

task Thread is
    entry Start;
    entry Quit;
end Thread;

By default a task is idle when not running.

Comment: Not yet clear how to solve my problem (see my post below) using entries: execute something at regular time intervals, and enable/disable this asynchronously. Answers to my question about a standard solution are welcome.

Comment: @hreba Take a look at Section 9 of Ada Reference Manual (ARM), https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-9.html. I think your requirement can be implemented using tasking features without needing protected object.

Comment: I attempted to post my implementation of @hreba requirement using tasking only. But my codes were rejected due to some unaccepted format. Unless you are not interest to see it, let me know I will find other way to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comments, the program is working correctly now.

To Jesper Quorning:

"Time in past" was not a problem here, but could be so in my real software project. I included a remedy nevertheless in the corrected version below, so it could serve as a pattern for others. Thanks for the hint.

To Niklas Holsti:

I shifted "delay until" out of the protected operation and the program now works as expected, thanks for the explanation. (Sometimes a program which works badly is worse than one which doesn't work at all, because in the latter case you take compiler warnings more seriously.)

What I want to do is:

- Execute an application at precisely defined time intervals
- Being able to enable/disable it anytime
- Giving it time to stop only when in a well defined state
- Knowing, when it really has stopped
- Controlled termination of the whole thing.

My idea of realization was:

- Call the application in an endless loop as separate task
- Check whether exit has been requested at the top of the loop
- An if statement which executes the application if enabled
- Simple delay otherwise.
  Control from other packages is done with the public subprograms
  Start, Is_Running, Request_Stop, Request_Quit.
  Besides the corrections mentioned above, I renamed some items to make their role clearer.

If there is a standard solution, different from mine, I would like to see it.

Here comes my corrected program:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;

package body Tasking is
   
   t_step:  constant Duration:= 0.1;
      
   protected Sync is
      procedure Enable_App;         -- enable application
      procedure Request_Disable;    -- request disabling of app.
      procedure Disable_If_Req;     -- disable app. if requested
      function Enabled return Boolean;  -- application is enabled
      procedure Request_Quit;           -- task shall terminate
      function Quit_Requested return Boolean;   -- task termination requested
      procedure Set_Time (t: Ada.Calendar.Time);    -- set execution time
      function Get_Time return Ada.Calendar.Time;   -- get execution time
   private
      running:  Boolean:= false;        -- application is enabled
      stopreq:  Boolean:= false;        -- disabling has been requested
      quitreq:  Boolean:= false;        -- task termination requested
      ti:   Ada.Calendar.Time;      -- time of next app. execution
   end Sync;
   
   protected body Sync is
      
      procedure Enable_App is begin running:= true; end Enable_App;
      
      procedure Request_Disable is
      begin
     if running then stopreq:= true; end if;
      end Request_Disable;
      
      procedure Disable_If_Req is
      begin
     if stopreq then
        running:= false;
        stopreq:= false;
     end if;
      end Disable_If_Req;
      
      function Enabled return Boolean is
      begin return running; end Enabled;
      
      procedure Request_Quit is
      begin quitreq:= true; end Request_Quit;
      
      function Quit_Requested return Boolean
      is begin return quitreq; end Quit_Requested;
      
      procedure Set_Time (t: Ada.Calendar.Time) is
      begin ti:= t; end Set_Time;
      
      function Get_Time return Ada.Calendar.Time is
     begin return ti; end Get_Time;
      
   end Sync;
   
   
   task body Thread is
      use type Ada.Calendar.Time;
      now:  Ada.Calendar.Time;
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("starting task");
      while not Sync.Quit_Requested loop
     if sync.Enabled then
        -- increment time if it is too late
        now:= Ada.Calendar.Clock;
        while sync.Get_Time <= now loop
           sync.Set_Time (sync.Get_Time + t_step);
        end loop;
        -- wait until next execution time
        delay until sync.Get_Time;
        -- execute application and set time for next execution
        Ada.Text_IO.Put(".");
        sync.Set_Time (sync.Get_Time + t_step);
        -- disable application if this has been requested
        sync.Disable_If_Req;
     else
        -- wait for enabling and set time for next execution
        delay t_step;
        sync.Set_Time (Ada.Calendar.Clock + t_Step);
     end if;
       end loop;
   end Thread;
   
   
   procedure Start is
   begin
      Sync.Enable_App;
   end Start;
   
   function Is_Running return Boolean is
   begin
      return Sync.Enabled;
   end Is_Running;
   
   procedure Request_Stop is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("");
      Sync.Request_Disable;
   end Request_Stop;
   
   procedure Request_Quit is
   begin
      Sync.Request_Quit;
   end Request_Quit;
   
end Tasking;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general ideas about Ada tasking:

- Conceptually, an Ada task has its own processor that no other task runs on. Scheduling, such as determining when the task should next do something, is usually the task's responsibility.
- When the task has to wait for an event, it is usually best for the task to block than to poll.
- Ada.Calendar is typically local time, and can even go backward. Tasks should schedule themselves with Ada.Real_Time if possible.

So I would do something like

```
protected Control is
   procedure Set_Running (Running : in Boolean := True);
   -- Set whether the task should run or not
   -- Initially Running is False

   entry Wait_Until_Running;
   -- Blocks the caller until Running is set to True

   function Running return Boolean;
   -- Returns the current value of Running

   procedure Quit_Now;
   -- Tell the task to quit

   function Quitting return Boolean;
   -- Returns True when Quit_Now has been called; False otherwise
private -- Control
   Run  : Boolean := False;
   Quit : Boolean := False;
end Control;

task body T is
   Step : constant Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span := Ada.Real_Time.Milliseconds (100);

   Next : Ada.Real_Time.Time;
begin -- T
   Forever : loop
      Control.Wait_Until_Running;
      Next := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;

      Run : while Control.Running loop
         exit Forever when Control.Quitting;

         delay until Next;

         Next := Next + Step;
         -- The task does its thing here
         Ada.Text_IO.Put (Item => 'a');
      end loop Run;
   end loop Forever;
end T;

protected body Control is
   procedure Set_Running (Running : in Boolean := True) is
   begin
      Run := Running;
   end Set_Running;

   entry Wait_Until_Running when Run is
   begin
      null;
   end Wait_Until_Running;

   function Running return Boolean is (Run);

   procedure Quit_Now is
   begin
      Run := True; -- Release the task if it is blocked on Wait_Until_Running
      Quit := True;
   end Quit_Now;

   function Quitting return Boolean is (Quit);
end Control;
```

Comment: Thanks for your upgrade of my program, and the very clear application of the entry concept, which I haven't  ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your new description of the goals, @hreba, and good to hear that your program is working as expected now.

I agree with @Anh Vo that the application task could be controlled with task entries, but I think that using a protected object (PO) is mostly preferable because it decouples the caller (the main task) from the application task -- it does not make the caller wait until the application task is ready to accept the entry call. However, I would reduce the PO to handle the inter-task communication. In the @hreba code, I see no reason for the protected operations Set_Time and Get_Time, as the timing seems completely controlled by the application task anyway.

Here is how I would program this. First, instead of a number of Booleans I would define an enumeration for the state of the application task:

```
type App_State is (Enabled, Disabled, Stopping, Stopped);
```

In the @hreba code, it seems the application task is initially "not running", so

```
Initial_State : constant App_State := Disabled;
```

The PO would then be declared as (I leave out the comments because I will comment in prose):

```
protected App_Control is
   procedure Enable;
   procedure Disable;
   procedure Stop;
   entry Get_New_State (New_State : out App_State);
   entry Wait_Until_Stopped;
private
    State : App_State := Initial_State;
    Old_State : App_State := Initial_State;
end App_Control;
```

The PO operations Enable, Disable, and Stop do the evident things:

```
procedure Enable
is
begin
   State := Enabled;
end Enable;
```

and analogously for Disable and Stop. Stop sets State to Stopping.

The entry Get_New_State will be called in the application task to receive the new state. It is an entry, instead of a function or a procedure, so that it can be made callable only when the state has changed:

```
entry Get_New_State (New_State : out App_State)
when State /= Old_State
is
begin
   New_State := State;
   Old_State := State;
   if State = Stopping then
      State := Stopped;
   end if;
end Get_New_State;
```

Here I made an automatic transition from Stopping to Stopped as soon as the application task has been given New_State = Stopping. If the application task has to do some clean-up before it can be considered really stopped, that transition should be moved to a separate operation, for example procedure App_Control.Has_Stopped, to be called from the application task after that clean-up.

The entry Wait_Until_Stopped can be called in the main task to wait until the application task has stopped. It is very simple:

```
entry Wait_Until_Stopped
when State = Stopped
is
begin
   null;
end Wait_Until_Stopped;
```

Now for the application task. My design differs in one main point from the original: to make the task more responsive to "stop" commands, I use a timed entry call of Get_New_State to let that call take place while the application task is waiting for its next activation time. This may not matter much if the task is running every 0.1 s, but in some other scenario the task might be running every 10 s, or every 10 minutes, and then it could matter a great deal. So here is the task body:

```
task body App_Thread
is
   use Ada.Calendar;
   Period : constant Duration := 0.1;
   State : App_State := Initial_State;
   Next_Time : Time := Clock + Period;
begin
   loop
      select
         App_Control.Get_New_State (New_State => State);
         exit when State = Stopping;
      or
         delay until Next_Time;
         if State = Enabled then
            Execute_The_Application;
         end if;
         Next_Time := Next_Time + Period;
      end select;
   end loop;
end App_Thread;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the program and the detailed explanations. For me it is an excelent example for learning the barrier and select concepts, I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

To uncouple between calling task and called task, do not use accept {entry name} do statement. Just break this into two separate statements as shown below with entry Start_Work for example

--coupling case
accept Start_Work do
Execute_The_Application
end Start_Work;

--uncoupling case
accept Start_Work;
Execute_The_Application;

Comment: That only uncouples the /end/ of the Start_Work rendez-vous from Execute_The_Application so that the call of Start_Work returns, and the caller can continue, while Execute_The_Application runs (which is what @hreba wants, to be sure). It does not change the fact that if the caller task tries to call some entry again, for example a Stop entry, it has to wait until the called task executes an accept for that entry, so possibly it has to wait for the whole of Execute_The_Application, which could make the GUI very unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of @hreba's requirement.

package Tasking is
-- more codes

```
task Thread2 is
    entry Start_Work;
    entry Stop_Work;
    entry Quitting_Time;
end Thread2;

task body Thread2 is
    use type Ada.Real_Time.Time;
    T_Step : constant Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span := Ada.Real_Time.Milliseconds (100);
    Next_Time : Ada.Real_Time.Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;
begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("task Thread2 elaborates and activates");

    Forever: loop
        select
            accept Quitting_Time;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("task Thread2 terminates. Later alligator");
                exit Forever;  -- later alligator
        or
            accept Start_Work;
            Working: loop
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Ada");
                Next_Time := Next_Time + T_Step;
                select
                    accept Stop_Work;
                    exit Working;
                or
                    delay until Next_Time;
                end select;
            end loop Working;
        or
            Terminate;
        end select;
    end loop Forever;   
end Thread2;
```

-- more codes
end Tasking;

Comment: Not sure about the Terminate alternative, neither semantics nor purpose. When is it called? What should it do?

Comment: Just replace calls Sync.Start by Thread2.Start_Work, Sync.Request_Stop by Thread2.Stop_Work and Sync.Request_Quit by Thread2.Quitting_Time. The Select Terminate alternative allows Threads task to terminates when the program terminates in case Quitting_Time is not called. In addition, the result should be the same. By the way, I used Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Ada"); in place of Ada.Text_IO.Put ("a"); for easy to follow the output.